# Updating a textview in different layout xml from the MainAcivity.java?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-widget, textview

I've created a new .xml file in my layout folder called game.xml. It contains an TextView.

Is it possible to set the text on the textview located in the game.xml from my main activity?

game.xml (Textview part)

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tV1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="TextView" />
```

MainActivity.java

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setImageArray();
    String actualword = chooseWord(words);
    createLetterArray(actualword);
    TextView textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tV1); //get a reference to the textview on the game.xml file.
    textView1.setText(actualword);

}
    ...
```

I tried it this way. But it doesn't work. Anyone who can help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't set a view, `TextView` here, that hasn't been created by inflating the layout through an inflater or `setContentView()`. You can pass the value through an `Intent` to the class that will actually use the `TextView`

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NextActivity.class); 
intent.putExtra("key", actualword);
startActivity(intent);
```

Where `NextActivity` is the activity that will display the textview

Then you can get that value and set it in your other activity

```
Intent recIntent = getIntent();
String text = recIntent.getStringExtra("key");
TextView textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tV1); //get a reference to the textview on the game.xml file.
textView1.setText(text);
```

After you have used `setContentView(R.layout.game);` in `onCreate()` of your second activity

Answer (score 0):

Short Answer, No

The layout file is just a blueprint. The actual textview doesn't exist until the layout has been inflated (turned into the views).

My question, (how) are you're not using this game.xml? Is it in another activity?